# GStreamer not sending UDP packets

Tags: gstreamer

I am fairly new to GStreamer, and without any error messages I am lost trying to debug my problem. I am trying to stream a h264 stream as RTP packets over UDP:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src ! 'video/x-raw, width=1280, height=720, framerate=30/1' ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=192.168.88.1 port=5004
```

Output:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
Redistribute latency...
```

When I do a netcat on 192.168.88.1 I see nothing:

```
nc -ul 5004
```

And neither VLC nor Janus Gateway are picking up any stream. I am honestly shooting in the dark because I'm not very familiar with gstreamer or video streaming in general. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I've also tried using h264parse after x264enc, and removing videoconvert but had the same result.

Comment: Sending it to 127.0.0.1 makes netcat print stuff on the same machine so I guess the pipeline works and is sending data. Perhaps something is wrong when sending data to another host?